# I am not able to deploy my next.js app in Vercel (and Netlify)

Tags: next.js, deployment

I have tried everything but nothing seems to work. It shows me this error when try to deploy it in **Vercel**.
[image]

I also can't seem to deploy it in **Netlify** and can't seem to know what the problem is.

Here's my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "onlinestore",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.25",
    "autoprefixer": "10.4.14",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "next": "13.4.10",
    "postcss": "8.4.26",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.3"
  }
}
```

I also get this error when i type `npm run build` in the terminal:

[image]